# Trouble SSHing into Raspberry Pi with Passwordless SSH Key on Ubuntu Core 20

Tags: networking, ssh, password, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I have successfully created a bootable Ubuntu Core 20 SD card using Raspberry Pi Imager. I generated an SSH key using PuTTY Key Generator without a password and added it to my Ubuntu account's SSH key importer. I've read that I should be able to SSH into my Pi without a password from my Windows machine using PuTTY or PowerShell (I have OpenSSH-client installed), but every time I try to SSH, it asks for a password. I'm not sure what password I'm supposed to enter.

I encountered a similar issue when attempting to SSH into the Pi from my Linux (Mint) machine, where I generated an SSH key using 'ssh-keygen' without a password. After typing 'yes,' it also asks for a password. This is my first time using a Pi and Ubuntu Core, and I didn't set a password during installation. I just want to know what I should enter in that password field to successfully SSH into my Pi3.

Comment: The most common reason for a new Ubuntu Core install to ask for a password is use of the wrong IP address.